# Invoking object's method vs. Invoking non object's method

Tags: javascript

What is the main difference between these two methods:

```
rect.setSize(width, height);
```

and

```
setRectSize(rect, width, height);
```

Why do I need to use first OOP approach (`rect.setSize(...)`)?

Comment: With the first you can use `this`.. But you can also use `this` with `setRectSize` by calling `setRectSize.call(rect, width, height)`

Comment: Do both that method and that function exist in your script?

Comment: Looks like one is a named function and the other is an opp function method. There is a difference. Now its hard to tell if rect is the object proto or is a returned object /element

Comment: This question does not make sense as a general issue; the answer entirely depends on the particular function involved.

Comment: Its the same functions. They do the same job - setting rectangle size.

Comment: I think the question mostly about OOP than about JavaScript.

Comment: _"Why do I need to use first"_ - You don't _need_ to.

Comment: In that case my code doesn't have OOP style.

Comment: I think the thing is in one of the major OOP principle - encapsulation. But I can't formulate this well.